# google maps api v3 - how to display image thumbnails inside bubble?

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps

I have some thumbnails with gps info that I want to pass to a javascript google maps instance. I can get the points to draw on the map, center and zoom to fit, and I can replace the markers with the thumbnails.

This is close, but I'm looking for something that I can style (border, size, etc) and show more of a precise location, like a popup bubble like in google maps business search.. I've looked at the chart library, but that doesn't seem to be anything more than text and their icons.

I also like the way the panoramio (when you turn on photos in a google map) will scale the majority of images down and deal with zooming.. are there public libraries or functions we can use that do this stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/Unh2M/embedded/result/ Its using an InfoWindow to display the picture when you click on the pin.

You can view the source on that at http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/Unh2M/ and check the reference on InfoWindows at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows