# Adding overlays to the Google Maps display itself

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlays

I'm looking for a way to add images to the Google Map interface itself, **not fixed on a point on the geographical map but on the Google Maps "window"**. Something to display Map Legends on the map itself.

I've been looking through the net but can't seem to find a way to do this. As you can tell I don't really know what this is called also, so that may be the reason why I ca

Comment: Use a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Comment: Are you asking about something like [this](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/legend) (a "legend")?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open infowindow on map and put image in it.

Try with this answer : [google maps api v3 - how to display image thumbnails inside bubble?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4514259)

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I need something that will always be visible wherever or whatever the user may be looking.

Comment: Then use css to display image on Google Map.